# How can I share an int variable from 1 JFrame to another?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am a total newbie in using Java and I would like to send the total input (`bal`) from `JFrame` 1 to frame 2 and put it inside a `JLabel` and use it for `if`/`else`.

This is the action I had made for frame 1 button:

```
private void btnProcessActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int input1 = Integer.parseInt(jtxt1P.getText());
    int input2 = Integer.parseInt(jtxt5P.getText());
    int input3 = Integer.parseInt(jtxt10P.getText());
    
    int bal = input1+(input2*5)+(input3*10);
    
    new Second(bal).setVisible(true);
   
    Second jf2 = new Second();
    jf2.show();
}
```

Comment: You seem to have done something with `new Second(bal)`, so what's the problem? Why do you need two instances of Second class?

Comment: As a random code quality note: You shouldn't have to write out the full package like this: `java.awt.event.ActionEvent`

Comment: *"I am a total newbie in using Java"* Making cross-platform GUIs in Java is not a 'newbie' task. Perhaps put GUIs aside for a while until you understand the basics (like parameter passing and variable scope). **General tips:** 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 3) For integer input, it is easier for both the user ***and*** the code to use a `JSpinner` with an integer based `SpinnerNumberModel`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by parameter passing.

Describe `frame2` as:

```
public jframe2(**int var**){}.
```

And call `jframe2` in frame 1 as:

```
jframe2 jf2=new jframe2(bal);
jf2.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: You can use single backticks for code blocks that look like: `this`. You can use triple backticks for multi like code blocks.